# arraylist not displaying properly

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am getting a response from my web services. I am adding the response to an arraylist.

```
model.addAttribute("suburbCreatedRequest", new ObjectFactory().createSuburbsrequesttype()); 
            model.addAttribute("addressCreatedRequest", new ObjectFactory().createStreetaddressrequesttype());
            suburbCreatedRequest.setSearchtype("SASU");  
            suburbCreatedRequest.setUsercodes("");   

            Suburbsresponsetype suburbCreatedResponse = new ObjectFactory().createSuburbsresponsetype();
            suburbCreatedResponse = (Suburbsresponsetype) ((JAXBElement<?>) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(suburbCreatedRequest)).getValue(); 
            model.addAttribute("suburbCreatedResponse", suburbCreatedResponse);
            model.addAttribute("suburbnamevalue", suburbCreatedRequest.getSuburbstring());


            newList.add(suburbCreatedResponse);
            model.addAttribute("newList", newList);
```

I want to display the arraylist in my jsp page. It's displaying the result but not in a proper way. My jsp page coding is like that.

```
<c:forEach var="suburb" items="${newList}" >
                    <a href="<portlet:actionURL>
                                <portlet:param name="action" value="streets"/>
                                <portlet:param name="suburbname" value="${suburb}"/>                                
                             </portlet:actionURL>"> ${suburb.suburbs.suburbname}
                    </a>
                    <br /><br />                    
                </c:forEach>
```

And the result is like that

```
[HABERFIELD, HACKS FERRY, HALEKULANI, HALFWAY CREEK, HALL, HALLIDAYS POINT, HALLORAN, HALLS CREEK, HALLSVILLE, HALTON, HAMBLEDON HILL, HAMILTON, HAMILTON EAST, HAMILTON NORTH, HAMILTON SOUTH, HAMILTON VALLEY, HAMLYN TERRACE, HAMMONDVILLE, HAMPDEN HALL, HAMPTON, HANGING ROCK, HANLEYS CREEK, HANNAM VALE, HANWOOD, HARDEN, HARDYS BAY, HAREFIELD, HARGRAVES, HAROLDS CROSS, HARPARARY, HARPERS HILL, HARRINGTON, HARRINGTON PARK, HARRIS PARK, HARTLEY, HARTLEY VALE, HARTWOOD, HARTYS PLAINS, HARWOOD, HARWOOD ISLAND, HASSALL GROVE, HASTINGS POINT, HAT HEAD, HATFIELD, HAVILAH, HAWKESBURY HEIGHTS, HAWKESBURY RIVER, HAWKS NEST, HAY, HAY SOUTH, HAYES GAP, HAYMARKET, HAYSTACK, HAYTERS HILL, HAYWARDS BAY, HAZELBROOK, HAZELGROVE]
```

But the expected result is:

HABERFIELD

HACKS FERRY

HALEKULANI

HALFWAY CREEK

HALL

HALLIDAYS POINT

HALLORAN

HALLS CREEK

HALLSVILLE

HALTON

HAMBLEDON HILL

HAMILTON

HAMILTON EAST

HAMILTON NORTH

HAMILTON SOUTH

HAMILTON VALLEY

HAMLYN TERRACE

HAMMONDVILLE

HAMPDEN HALL

HAMPTON

HANGING ROCK

HANLEYS CREEK

HANNAM VALE

HANWOOD

HARDEN

HARDYS BAY

HAREFIELD

HARGRAVES

HAROLDS CROSS

HARPARARY

HARPERS HILL

HARRINGTON

HARRINGTON PARK

HARRIS PARK

HARTLEY

HARTLEY VALE

HARTWOOD

HARTYS PLAINS

HARWOOD

HARWOOD ISLAND

HASSALL GROVE

HASTINGS POINT

HAT HEAD

HATFIELD

HAVILAH

HAWKESBURY HEIGHTS

HAWKESBURY RIVER

HAWKS NEST

HAY

HAY SOUTH

HAYES GAP

HAYMARKET

HAYSTACK

HAYTERS HILL

HAYWARDS BAY

HAZELBROOK

HAZELGROVE

Any help?

Comment: What do you need to do with your list of NSW suburbs?

Comment: When I will click on any of the links it will display all the streets under that suburbs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking a stab in the dark here because I don't know the structure of your jaxb objects, but I only see one item being added to your list. Have you tried this instead:

**EDITED**

```
<c:forEach var="suburb" items="${newList}" >
    <c:forEach var="suburbname" items="${suburb.suburbs.suburbname}">
        <a href="<portlet:actionURL>
                <portlet:param name="action" value="streets"/>
                <portlet:param name="suburbname" value="${suburbname}"/>
            </portlet:actionURL>"> ${suburbname}
        </a> <br /> <br />
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: The thing is, your newList has nothing but a single element, so your forEach is iterating over ONE item, no? Without more detail on your jaxb objects, I don't know what else to recommend. Ultimately, you are seeing the toString() of a List being printed, so somewhere down the line you are not iterating over the right property and instead printing out the string representation of that property. Is "suburbname" a list of strings by any chance??

Comment: yes it's a list of strings.I am already getting the strings. Something [harr1,harris2,harr3] like that. I want to display the result in a new line every time something like harr1                                                               harr2                                                               harr3

Comment: Hi  there i have done some changes on your coding and it's working. <c:forEach var="suburb" items="${newList}" >
     <c:forEach var="innerSuburb" items="${suburb.suburbs.suburbname}" >  Thanks a lot for your help
     <a href="<portlet:actionURL>
        <portlet:param name="action" value="streets"/>
        <portlet:param name="suburbname" value="${suburb.suburbs.suburbname}"/>        
        </portlet:actionURL>"> ${innerSuburb}
     </a>
     <br /><br />
    </c:forEach>      
    </c:forEach>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick help

Comment: If you feel my answer solved your problem, it would be appropriate to mark it as the answer.